# Unzip web files that change names every day

Tags: r

I have a R Script that needs to access a web link that contains a Zip file. Extract a specific Excel file and read it on PowerBI.

The link is the following:
https://portal.inmet.gov.br/uploads/dadoshistoricos/2022.zip

The file that I want is called "INMET_CO_MS_A756_AGUA CLARA_01-01-2022_A_31-03-2022.CSV", but as you can see I have a date (31/03/2022) at the end of the title and I need to change it manually every day. Today the file name is "INMET_CO_MS_A756_AGUA CLARA_01-01-2022_A_30-04-2022.CSV" and it will change periodically

I'm looking for a way to extract this file dynamically every day but I can't find it out.

```
install.packages("stringr")
library("stringr")

temp <- tempfile()
download.file("https://portal.inmet.gov.br/uploads/dadoshistoricos/2022.zip",temp, mode="wb")

unzip(temp, "INMET_CO_MS_A756_AGUA CLARA_01-01-2022_A_31-03-2022.CSV")
Tabela <- read.table("INMET_CO_MS_A756_AGUA CLARA_01-01-2022_A_31-03-2022.csv", sep=";", skip = 8)
unlink(temp)
```

Comment: Is it just the date that change every day (i.e., you can easily predict what the name is on any given day) or is the rest of the file name changing as well?

Comment: The date is the only that changes. But I can't predict the date because it's not the TODAY() date. Today, for example, the date at the file is Apr 30.

Comment: You could write a loop where you first try with today‘s date and if that fails, try the date from yesterday, then the day begore and so on. There‘s no way how R could figure out in advance what the website would call the file if there‘s no clear pattern (e.g. if they update it always at the end of a month).

Comment: the term "A756" is the name of the station that I want. So there is any way to search for this term inside the title? like InStr()